# How to mock network layer responses for automated Android Studio UI Espresso test suite?

Tags: android, testing, mocking, retrofit, uitest

My goal is to run a suite of Espresso UI Tests, and have the Retrofit instance that has been created in the `onCreate` method of my MainActivity reconfigured to return mocked JSON responses from `localhost`, so I can test how the app's UI responds to response codes and different JSON data, etc.

So far, I've tried to drop in the `MockWebServer` package, and I was able to get that up and running on a localhost server. However, the Retrofit instance was still configured to the production url.

I've tried passing arguments at the launch of a test, including manually setting the intent for the MainActivity with some `extras`, in an attempt to set a flag that could toggle the string used for the Retrofit instance. However, it seems that the any arguments set in `@Before` of a test don't get picked up at the launch of the MainActivity.

I've looked at these answers, but there doesn't appear to be a solution:

[Android Espresso UI Test with mocked Retrofit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904673/android-espresso-ui-test-with-mocked-retrofit-api)

[Mock server requests Android Espresso UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386652/mock-server-requests-android-espresso-ui-testing)

This is my latest experiment:

```
@get:Rule
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)

    @Before
    fun setup() {

    }

    @Test
    fun intent() {
        val intent = Intent()

        activityRule.launchActivity(intent.putExtra("UITesting", true))

        println(activityRule.activity.intent.extras)
    }
```

Here is the Retrofit instance:

```
var BASE_URL = "https://api.invoicehome.com"

class NetworkManager {

    private val service : networkService
    // initialization with BASE_URL, using Gson converter factory to decode ( i believe there are other options available as well)
    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        service = retrofit.create(networkService::class.java)
//    }
    }
 }
```

Beginning of MainActivity, where there's an instance of the `NetworkManager`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private var networkManager = NetworkManager()
}
```

I would like something that could simply wrap around the instance of Retrofit, and pop in a URL, but I'm 99% sure this isn't realistic. If any swift devs are looking at this, I'm looking for analogous functionality to `Swifter`.

So, can I somehow make the URL conditional for the Retrofit instance? Where would I pass in these flags? Is there a library that I'm missing that can do all of this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the help of [MockWebServer library](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)

You will need to abstract your `NetworkManager` class and make two different implementations, one for mocking the requests and the other for making real requests and provide this as a dependency to your activity.

So for example:

NetworkManager Interface

```
interface NetworkManager {

    fun doRequest()
}
```

Mock implementation

```
class MockedNetworkManager : NetworkManager {

    override fun doRequest() {
        // Mock request
    }
}
```

Real implementation

```
class RealNetworkManager : NetworkManager {

    override fun doRequest() {
        // Real request
    }
}
```

And your MainActivity should look something like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var networkManager: NetworkManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val shouldMock = intent.getBooleanExtra("UITesting", false)
        if (shouldMock) {
            networkManager = MockedNetworkManager()
        } else {
            networkManager = RealNetworkManager()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What if I want to make 10 different mock requests/responses?